# How spring evaluates SPEL internally?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

For example, we have an expression like this 'hasAnyRole("ROLE_1","ROLE_2")'

I know that Python has a function like eval to run code from a string. But how it works here? How Spring in Java parses the expression? Does it run it? If yes then how?

My primary question is how Python runs the string containing the expression. How does he understand what to do?

Comment: Do you mean how *Java* runs the string? This is too broad for SO, but Spring is open source, so you can see how it works at e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel

Comment: This isn't an "expression" in java... `hasAnyRole(String... args)` takes in a variable amount of arguments (var args) and turns it into an array

Comment: RobOhRob, but this is a string. How spring converts it to executable code?

Answer (score 2):

SpEL has a full-blown parser and builds an AST for the expression.

In this case, the evaluation calls the `hasAnyRole()` method on the root object for the evaluation.

You can dig into the details in a debugger to see the actual workings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You know everybody is trying to pretend that they know something. I was seeking for the answer for some time yet. Where you read this information? How do you investigate such rare questions? I see that you really know something. Not like others.

Comment: I am a committer on several Spring projects (for more than 10 years, and over 20 years Java experience); when I needed to understand how SpEL works a few years ago, I used a debugger and stepped into the code for a `expression.getValue()` call. It is very well written and easy to understand - if you have some basic understanding about how abstract syntax trees (AST) work.